# Windows + Qt + Cygwin

Tags: qt, lib, cygwin

Есть проект на Qt с некоторыми зависимостями, которые можно разрешить с помощью cygwin. Как объяснить Qt'у, где искать заголовочные файлы и библиотеки? Хардкоддить не вариант.

Comment: Что используете для сборки проекта?

Comment: Qt 4.8 + mingw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используете qt creator, то в pro-файл добавить:

```
INCLUDEPATH += путь/к/хидерам
DEPENDPATH += путь/к/хидерам
```

так же, скорее всего нужно будет добавить библиотеки, для этого добавить еще:

```
LIBS += -Lпуть/к/папке_с_библиотеками
LIBS += -lимя_библиотеки1
LIBS += -lимя_библиотеки2
```

Если Cygwin нужно часто подключать в разные проекты, то можно упростить процедуру.
В директории с Cygwin создать файл, к примеру, Cygwin.pri примерно такого содержания:

```
 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include
 DEPENEDPATH += $$PWD/include

 LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs
 LIBS += -lимя_библиотеки1
 LIBS += -lимя_библиотеки2
```

Ну или как они там расположены.
И затем в основном проекте достаточно подключать этот pri-файл:

```
include(путь/к/pri-файлу/cygwin.pri)
```

$$PWD - это текущий каталог pri-файла

такой подход удобен тем, чтоб можно подключать разные библиотеки в зависимости от типа сборки или наличия дефайнов, который нужно указать один раз при написание pri-файла.
Вот пример моей реализации:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD

HEADERS += $$PWD/propertybrowser.h

isEmpty(DESTDIR) {
    LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Builds
} else {
    LIBS += -L$${DESTDIR}
}

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -lPropertyBrowser$${MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX}_d
}
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    contains(DEFINES, STATIC) {
        LIBS += -lPropertyBrowser_static$${MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX}
    } else {
        LIBS += -lPropertyBrowser$${MYCOMPILER_POSTFIX}
    }
}
```

Comment: А общесистемно объявить никак? Cygwin на разных машинах может быть по разному установлен. Тут тогда правильнее было бы их в проекте сохранить и компилять, но основная платформа всё-таки linux, поэтому не хочу так делать.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: @anEagle, автор дополнил ответ. Александр, автор вопроса не получает уведомлений, если Вы просто меняете ответ. Чтобы человек получил уведомление, нужно упомянуть его явно(как я это сделал)

Comment: Хотелось конечно сделать это средствами ОС, чтобы прошки не трогать, но, как я понял, тут ничего не сделаешь. Спасибо за ответ. Сделал примерно также, только в профайле проекта обернул всё это дело в win32.

Comment: ну можно в системные переменные прописать пути, типа CYGWIN_LIB=путь к cygwin. а в проекте делать DEPENDPATH += $CYGWIN, не знаю работает ли это в qmake и не уверен на счет синтаксиса, но в visual studio такая штука прокатывает.